# How to save decimals in SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, decimal, sql-server-ce-3.5

`decimal` is a .NET (also other frameworks, rdbms and languages) value type that stores floating point numbers with decimal precision, instead of a binary one.

Is there any way of saving these values to a SQL CE database without using binary precision in the process?

Comment: Which edition of CE are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the full version SQL Server, SQL Server CE supports the `numeric` data type:

- [SQL Server Compact Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424(SQL.110).aspx)

In contrast to the `Decimal` data type in .NET, you will have to fix the precision and scale when creating a `numeric` field.

Answer (score 0):

Use [numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) data type of Sql server